# How to put thousands of text files into one single DAT file in R with certain formatting?

Tags: r

I have a text file,eg: file1.txt that has words like "aluminium, chlorine level,blood glucose, cardiac arrest, heart" separated by commas. This is the format followed in all the text files.

I need to combine all these 16,000 files into one DAT file but with the words before a comma having an underscore in between them so that they are considered as one word.

For the above example, "aluminium, chlorine_level, blood_glucose, cardiac_arrest, heart". And each text file separated by a line break like below.

aluminium, chlorine_level, blood_glucose, cardiac_arrest, heart
Matter, elements, energy_and_chemical
chemical_changes, atoms
etc

Comment: You could try something like `gsub(" ", "_", file)`

Comment: No Jentjr. It didn't work. May be I did something wrong. Here's what I had   teread=read.table("file1.txt")  
te=gsub(" ", "_" , teread)

Comment: Well `read.table` expects a space to be separating entries by default, so you maybe had no spaces left to change with `gsub`. Try `read.csv` or `read.table` with `sep=","`.

Comment: Maybe also try `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`.

Comment: I tried both the commands.  > te
  [1] "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1" "1"  this is the output I got for when using read.table with sep="," for all the words in that text file.  And for read.csv I got > te
 [1] "logical(0)" "logical(0)" "logical(0)" "logical(0)" "logical(0)" "logical(0)"

Comment: Yes, thanks @DaveTurek, stringAsFactors worked. But I also get an underscore in the beginning of each word.  > te
 [1] "_A1BG_gene"                                       
 [2] "_Alpha-1"                                         
 [3] "_AT-Rich_Interactive_Domain-Containing_Protein_1A"

Comment: You could do another substitution to remove the leading `_`: `gsub("^_","",te)`. The `^` matches the start of each word.

Comment: @DaveTurek,Yes, it worked to remove the underscore. But, I get the output as each word being in a separate line. I will need them to be in a single line. Each text file in one single line with the words between the commas having an underscore between them.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by each being on a separate line, but I think we may be barking up the wrong tree.  You are not trying to read data into R. You want to concatenate a bunch of text files into a single text file, and then do a substitution of "_" for " ", (except for the leading spaces you have). And you are thinking to use R to accomplish this. Is this correct?